# Emulator is already running but not able to see it in ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-emulator

I am using ubuntu 12.04,and Eclipse Platform Version: 3.7.2, I have one issue which i observed occasionally on my system I dont know whether this issue is common and did't find any related question so asked..                                                                                             problem is - "when I tried to launch android application using emulator(API level 17 Nexus 4),it runs fine no problem and emulator is in front of me, But the moment i open other window like browser,editor it hides and i am not able to see it.." Log says that emulator is ruuning but dont know where it hide.

Comment: can u see emulator icon on left panel?

Comment: No in Left panel icon is not there and when i tried to switch window using Alt+tab than there also emulator window is not there....well it does't happen all the time when i restart the system problem is resolved but after some days it comes again.. so that is the reason i want a better solution than restart, as sometimes by restarting i loose my work that is going on...

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is facing this problem, it could be due to memory overwhelming. To solve, in Ubuntu, go to Home/.android/avd/Pixel_X_API_XX.avd

and delete the *lock files, then Run the emulator as usually.
Where I wrote Pixel_X_API_XX.avd it means, for example : Pixel_2_API_32.avd
Bye bye